# Getting a java.io.InvalidClassException when trying to save and read a file

Tags: java, serialization, io

```
public static void save(Settings settings) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = 
                new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(settingsFile));
        os.writeObject(settings);
        os.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code that saves a class     Settings    to a file.

```
public static Settings load() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream is = 
                new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(settingsFile));
        Settings settings = (Settings) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        return settings;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code will read the file and return the     Object     which is cast to     Settings

The error is get is at

```
Settings settings = (Settings) is.readObject();
```

and the StackTrace is

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.Settings; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5215625451621355973, local class serialVersionUID = -6263468811172060812
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at com.Settings.load(Settings.java:51)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Im not entirely sure why I am getting this error because the object that is written to the file is Settings and the object that is being read is also Settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Settings`? Did you change the class definition since you last serialized the object?

Comment: Wow I feel silly. I edited something in the Settings class after I serialized it and to your point, I think that was messing it up. I just reserialized the file and it works perfectly. If you put that as an answer i'll mark it solved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you serialized is at version `X` and the current `Settings` class you are using is at version `Y` (where versions is the version UID that every `Serializable` has, even if you don't define one, it will generated by Java by looking at your class internals)

In future definiting a `private (no matter, it could be public/protected too) static final long serialVersionUID` inside the classes you make Serializable, with a value (for example `1L`) will avoid this problems.

To fix your exception for now define a `serialVersionUID` with value `5215625451621355973` (so they will match) and deserialize it. (And it's not safe.)

Anyway I would just should reserialize it with the new UID value (1L?) to make it ALWAYS compatible because you could encourage others errors if you don't provide this value.

The [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) JavaDoc explains this better than me.

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```
>
> If a
>   serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID,
>   then the serialization runtime will calculate a default
>   serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the
>   class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
>   the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
>   array classes.

Comment: I get it now. This was my first time trying to use Serializable. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) If your question is resolved, consider accepting my answer (or any other answer that helped you)

Answer (score 0):

check  serialVersionUID   in your code - which is a universal version identifier for a Serializable class.

e.g. `static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`

Deserialization uses this number to ensure that a loaded class corresponds exactly to a serialized object. If no match is found, then an InvalidClassException is  thrown